# AppleScript : CMD + S

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I can't manage to keystroke Command + S on an app, it's seems to trigger "Save AS" instead of "Save"

```
 tell application "TextMate 2"
    activate

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "S" using {command down} 
    end tell

    --
end tell
```

I don't have "shift" in my keystroke so I don't know why I can just save my documents without any extra windows.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Lower Case s.

```
keystroke "s" using {command down}
```

However, it would be better to issue a `save` command directly, rather than 'fake' keyboard input.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why, but this is working alright! Thank you

Comment: Presumably capital S is seen as "Shift S".